# Hadoop PIG with nested Json

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-pig

I have a list of movies with ratings by user.

```
    {"_id":59607,"title":"King Corn (2007)",
     "genres":["Documentary"],
     "ratings":[ {"userId":1860,"rating":3},
                {"userId":9970,"rating":3.5},
                {"userId":16929,"rating":1.5},
                {"userId":23473,"rating":4},
                {"userId":23733,"rating":4},
                {"userId":27584,"rating":3},
                {"userId":28232,"rating":4},
                {"userId":29482,"rating":3},
                {"userId":40976,"rating":5},
                {"userId":44631,"rating":4},
                {"userId":47613,"rating":3},
                {"userId":49763,"rating":3},
                {"userId":58160,"rating":4.5},
                {"userId":62249,"rating":3},
                {"userId":65923,"rating":4},
                {"userId":67507,"rating":4},
                {"userId":68259,"rating":3.5},
                {"userId":70331,"rating":5},
                {"userId":71420,"rating":3.5}
        ]
    }
```

I need to count how many ratings are done by every user. This is my attempt to get in the ratings.

```
a = load '/movies_1m.json' using JsonLoader('id:int, title : chararray, genres : { ( genre : chararray ) }, ratings: { ( userId : int, rating: float) } ');
```

then

```
b = FOREACH a GENERATE FLATTEN(ratings);
```

describe give me following:

```
b: {ratings::userId: int,ratings::rating: float}
```

just to count the users I need to access the inside of ratings. But this is the point where it is not succeeding. I tried this:

```
c = FOREACH b GENERATE COUNT(ratings);
```

it gets me an error.

I need to get something like this:

```
 {userId: int, rating: float}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `GROUP` in order to `COUNT` since that is an aggregate operation.

```
b = FOREACH a GENERATE FLATTEN(ratings);
gr = GROUP b by ratings::userId;
c = FOREACH gr GENERATE group,COUNT($1);
\d c
```

Output

Note, none of the users in your example repeat, so these are all one.

```
(1860,1)
(9970,1)
(16929,1)
(23473,1)
(23733,1)
(27584,1)
(28232,1)
(29482,1)
(40976,1)
(44631,1)
(47613,1)
(49763,1)
(58160,1)
(62249,1)
(65923,1)
(67507,1)
(68259,1)
(70331,1)
(71420,1)
```